# Stuck at converting/implementing Qt (.ui) files to Qtjambi(.jui) files

Tags: java, qt, bash, qt-jambi

### Edit 01.02.2012:

> FWIW: 4.7.0 linux packages are broken AFAIK, they
>      can be fixed or 4.6 packages used   instead...
>      No need to use 
>      custom Qt for Jambi – Smar 2 days ago
>
> Thanks to SMAR, I was finally able to resolve this
>    issue by downloading the an older version of 
>    qtjambi 4.6.3 ( http://qt-jambi.org/downloads/ ). The only problem was that the
>    designer did not know where to find my jvm which
>    I solved by adding these two entries to /etc/bash.bashrc:

```
  # custom PATH exports
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
    PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

> Then I just had to run (everything was in the qtjambi-folder):
>   designer.sh --> save it as .jui --> convert it with juic into a .java file --> and load it with netbeans :)
>
> Hope this is somehow helpful to others too.
>
> **Thanks for the great and fast help!**

---

### Original post:

Good evening,

I am not completely sure if this topic is enough about programming but I am having some problems setting up Qtjambi. I have followed a lot of "howtos" and instructions so I am a little confused about what to do next. Qtjambi works as I have written a example program with netbeans. Although I have created some ui files that I want to implement which doesnt work.
I am trying to get this to run for like a week and I really need this because of my finals in 2 months. I **try** to give as much useful  details as possible.

I am using LinuxMint (ubuntu derivate), downloaded qtjambi v 4.7.0
after trying out

```
bash qtjambi.sh
```

I got an error of mismatching versions

```
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x40704) with this library (version 0x40700)
```

So I downloaded, compiled and installed

**qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0**  to   **/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.0/**

I know that I have to tell the system where to find all the binarys so I added to the **/etc/bash.bashrc**

```
    #custom PATH exports
    PATH=$PATH:/home/michi/Scripts
    PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.0/bin/

    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.0/lib
    export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.0/plugins

    JAVA_DIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/
    export JAMBI_PATH=/usr/local/lib/qtjambi-linux64-community-4.7.0/
```

I followed through the instructions of:

```
    http://www.davidlauzon.net/2010/01/getting-started-with-qt-jambi-on-linux/
    Which generally talks about getting jambi-designer to work.

    http://jpnurmi.kapsi.fi/blog/2008/03/16/how-to-switch-qt-version-in-ubuntu/
    How to manage multiple Qt versions.. These commands worked but had no effect
```

I finally gave up on trying to run the designer and tried to "convert" the .ui files to .jui files with the program **juic** which is located in the qtjambi/bin folder. But also here I get an error:

```
    michi@BALMORA ~/Documents/unterlagen/pr_scw/Qt/Qtrainer/test $ which juic
    /usr/local/bin/juic
    michi@BALMORA ~/Documents/unterlagen/pr_scw/Qt/Qtrainer/test $ juic -cp .
    juic: no .jui files found in CLASSPATH

     michi@BALMORA ~/Documents/unterlagen/pr_scw/Qt/Qtrainer/test $ /usr/locallib/qtjambi-linux64-community-4.7.0/bin/juic -cp .
    juic: no .jui files found in CLASSPATH
```

It would be great if you could help/guide or redirect me to "better" instructions.

Michael Kargl

Comment: FWIW: 4.7.0 linux packages are broken AFAIK, they can be fixed or 4.6 packages used instead... No need to use custom Qt for Jambi

Comment: THANKS A LOT for your answer!! I finally could manage to get the jambi-designer working. I downloaded the qtjambi4.6.3 and everything just worked. I only had to set JAVA_HOME so that designer.sh knows where to find the jvm. I am going to update it above too... Big Thank you! Have a nice day